# A counting problem with a circular arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

I generally have trouble doing counting problems like the one below. Here's one I recently encountered.

A twin brother and sister plan a birthday dinner with their uncle and five friends. All eight people will sit at a circular table. The twins need to sit together and Uncle Tom can not sit next to the twins. How many different seating arrangements are possible?

This problem comes with a choice of some answers: 22, 84, 144, 192, and 300.

So I would assume that rotated arrangements don't count twice.

Comment: Why not write out your attempt(s)?  First, though, you should clarify which arrangements are equivalent.  Are rotated orders the same?  What about reflected?

Comment: have you tried turning it linear ?

Comment: None of those answers are correct.  (Hint: one of them would have been correct if there had been four friends instead of five.)